# Standard practice for keeping baseline dependent data common across environments

Tags: sql, database, continuous-integration, devops, data-migration

I've searched Google and SO but haven't been able to articulate my question well enough in a search query to get a clear answer.

I'm looking to understand what is the standard for having common reference data that is required across dev, test, staging and production environments.

As an example, I have a web application with a `dbo.status` table. I have predefined a series of statuses such as:

```
ID | name
---------
 1 | Created
 2 | In Progress
 3 | Completed
 4 | Deactivated
```

While other tables such as `dbo.user`, `dbo.company` etc can be populated differently in different environments, I would want to have a consistent reference to the various statuses in the `dbo.status` table in different parts of my web app, namely, things like:

```
if (status.id === 4) {
  do_some_stuff();
};
```

Obviously, this creates a data dependency that `status.id === 4` should mean the same thing, in different environments. If in one environment `status.id === 4` refers to `Restarted` then I'm in trouble.

I wanted to check:

1. Is having predefined data in a database best practice or should I be hardcoding such values into parts of the codebase that can be checked into source control?
2. If it IS acceptable, should this be incorporated as some sort of database initalisation script?
3. If none of the above, are there any alternatives to my approach I should be considering?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can include `insert` statements into the database setup script and use consistent values across all the environments. And to make the code verbose you may add the unique `code` column with values `RESTARTED` etc not to guess what is the meaning of 4.

Comment: Just as a side note, it is better practice to use values rather than codes in your code e.g. if (status.name === 'Deactivated') {... This makes your code more readable for anyone trying to support it and also makes it less likely that if you reference data is changed that you code doesn't break 'silently' e.g. if someone changed 4=Created your code is likely to still run but return the wrong records

Comment: @jzia . . . I would probably suggest having all environments reference the production environment in such a case.  That said, I think such as table is really outside the scope of the given project and should be in a different database which can be accessed by all the environments.

Comment: Thanks all:
@astentx: I think I'll use the `insert` as part of a CI/CD workflow for the time being. 
@GordonLinoff: Your point is well made, and have made a note to split globally scoped data into a separate DB in our next sprint, will just require a few changes.
@all: Noted with thanks on using names instead of Ids.